# Help with modeling a turret's arm from Portal 2

Tags: modeling

I am quite new with blender and I've been trying to model a turret from Portal 2. I've managed to create it's body but I have no idea how I can create it's arm. Look:
[image: Blueprint I found on internet]

It would be a christmas gift if someone teached me how to create the arm. Thanks for your attention

Comment: This is probably not the answer you want, but if you’re here to learn Blender, start from square one and work your way up to a car tutorial (where you’ll learn how to create that type of shape). If you’re just doing this as a one-off, you’re better off purchasing the model online—I see one for just $9. The Stack Exchange isn’t for project assistance, but we can help with specific problems as they arise. Sounds to me like you’re simply in too deep for your skill level.

Comment: In my head I thought it was something simple to do, that's why I made this question. But thanks for explaining

Comment: No problem. The quick answer you’re looking for is: take a plane, stretch it to a rectangle, round the top and bottom with edge loops and proportional editing, then slightly round the length with more edge loops and proportional editing, and solidify. If any of that doesn’t make sense, you should give yourself a Christmas present and search BlenderGuru on YouTube. Good luck, and welcome to the Exchange!

Comment: Thanks for the patience. I will!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is quite simple.

1. Add the torus.
2. Go to edit mode and cut the half of it (actually more than a half) in "face mode".
3. Flatten this figure a bit.
4. Use a preset viewpoint (any dot of navigation "cube" that lets you to see the figure at a whole).
5. Enable "Snap - Increment", choose tick strict snap to grid, and snap the figure to grid. Add three separate dots (left/right mouse button + Click). Snap them to grid too!

---

### [image: Pic1]

6. Select all (A button) and use Bisect. Connect dots to slice the figure.
7. Select  everything that you don't need and delete. Disable snap.

---

### [image: Pic2]

8. "Extrude along normals" this figure.

---

### [image: Pic3]

9. Voila! Then you can add other inner parts that are simpler.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the steps! Merry christmas <3

Comment: Welcome! And happy holidays to you too =)

Answer (score 0):

1. Model the egg shape of the body then make a copy
2. Make an object to boolean the cutline so the part can fit back again when not deployed
3. Adjust topology and edgeloops using the copy from the model without the boolean and skinwrap
4. Add solidify Modifier

Comment: Thanks a lot! <3